# 2 different wordpress cmses on one server, subdomain on younger blog redirects to the older one

Tags: wordpress, dns, freebsd, subdomain

I am currently running on the newest freebsd 64 bit server 9~
the problem is that I have:

- 2 seperate blogs on my server with two different domains
- The older one was "donosiciele.pl" - works fine
- The newer one "digsite.cat" has a subdomain multisite configured.

Lets cut to the chase. I do not have a dns wildcard ( *.digsite.cat ) so I had to edit my namedb file digsite.cat.db. After www I added subdomains for scary.digsite.cat and so on.

```
www                     A       37.59.20.16
scary                   A       37.59.20.16
music                   A       37.59.20.16
fashion                 A       37.59.20.16
```

The problem is that when you go to www.digsite.cat everything is fine, www.donosiciele.pl - fine

www.music.digsite.cat - you will get redirected to the "elder/1st" wordpress cms which runs under www.donosiele.pl

I have no idea how to deal with the problem, and I thoroughly search wordpress forums for that.

Comment: This looks to be a web server configuration issue not an issue with DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that is to create an apache virtual host for the given subdomain :)